# jQuery: Switch from submit buttons to <a>-tag

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change a lot of button controls to a-href and keep the functionality:

Thus I decided to create a hidden tag based on the id of the a-tag and use this to decide how to process the request:

```
var $hidden = $("<input type='hidden'/>", { name: $(this).attr("id") });                         
$("form").append($hidden).submit();
```

Unfortunately, the above-mentioned code just creates an empty input tag of type hidden but without the "name"-tag.

The following code works, but is ugly:

```
var $timeVar = $("<input type='hidden' name='"+$(this).attr("id")+"'/>");
```

What's goind on there?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't do that! Just use CSS to let the buttons look like links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can do this:

```
var $hidden = $("<input type='hidden'/>").attr({ name: $(this).attr("id") });
```

You can also just append it straight to the form by chaining:

```
$("<input type='hidden'/>").attr({ name: $(this).attr("id") }).appendTo("form");
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can't mix adding attributes directly in the string of the tag as well as in the 2nd parameter.  Just move all attributes into the same place:

```
var $hidden = $("<input/>", { 
                  name: $(this).attr("id"),
                  type: "hidden"
              });
```